# Como Pegar informações de uma coluna de uma coluna de uma tabelas e de uma coluna de outra tabela e exibir em um resultado só?

Tags: sql-server

> /*Neste caso eu quero pegar todas as ordens feitas em 1997 e o valor
>   das 10 melhores e exibir porém o anos está na tabela Orders e o valor
>   está na tabela Orders Details*/

select OrderDate
From Orders 
Where Year (OrderDate) = 1997 
Order by OrderDate

Select TOP(10)
    (Quantity*UnitPrice) as Total
From [Order Details]
Order By Total desc

Comment: Existe algum campo que correlacione as linhas de cada tabela? Se existir utilize JOIN.

Comment: pf edite sua pergunta, o titulo está confuso, e coloque na pergunta tbm a estrutura das tabelas